# ASP.NET Identity with mongodb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm learning and trying to make a token based authentication for my project using this article:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

I'm in a step, where I should add a package `"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework"` and my question is, if I can change this package to `"AspNet.Identity.Mongo"`, follow the steps and the rest should be fine? I mean, if it's that easy, or there is a lot more to do, that I don't see for now.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are not stored on the server side they are issued to clients and server requests clients to present them  on each call. Its unnecessary to store the token on the database side unless the protection key OWIN uses changes, never mess with this key bad things might happen, and lastly clients hold on to tokens until they are no longer valid.

The package "*Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework*" is used by ASP Identity for creating user and role tables for authorization configuration purposes hence for authentication purposes only your app never touches this api.